# Why my Flutter Scaffold back button always return to root?

Tags: flutter, navigation

If I have stacks of screens: A -> B -> C, whethen I press back button on the simulator or press back button on the Scaffold's back button on C, I always returned to A, not B. Why? And how to fix it? I searched on the

Here's how I push and pop. These code are simplified to only show the push/pop and screen build functions.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: UserListPage()
    );
  }
}



class UserListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListPageState createState() => _UserListPageState();
}

class _UserListPageState extends State<UserListPage> {
  ...
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("User list")),
        body: Builder(builder: (context) { 
          InkWell(
            onTap: () { 
              Navigator.push(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SessionListPage(userId: users[index].id)
              ),
            child: ...
          })
        }),
      );
    }
    ...
}



class SessionListPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final int userId;

  SessionListPage({ this.userId }) : super();

  @override
  _SessionListPageState createState() => _SessionListPageState();
}

class _SessionListPageState extends State<SessionListPage> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Session list")),
        body: Builder(builder: (context) { 
          InkWell(
            onTap: () { 
              Navigator.push(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DrawingPage(userId: widget.userId, sessionId: sessions[index].id)
              ),
            child: ...
          })
      }),
    );
  }

  ...
}


class DrawingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int userId;
  final int sessionId;

  DrawingPage({ this.userId, this.sessionId }) : super();

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<DrawingPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Enter the Number")),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          InkWell(
            onTap: () { Navigator.pop(context); } // here it returns straight to UserListPage instead of SessionListPage
            child: ...
          })
      }
    ));
  }
}
```

One thing that I noticed is that for the context that was supplied to push and pop, is from Builder instead of the context supplied from Widget build function. Does it have any impact?

Comment: Did you checked my code?

Comment: hi @NikhilVadoliya . I checked your code, it contains the basic Flutter starting code with "push button" demo. Are you sure you gave me the correct link?

Comment: This link was expire that why

Comment: I will share it

Answer (score 0):

> Please remove `super();` from all places.

Answer (score 0):

Young, It's working fine. Please check below link

[Code](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)